# can't insert into the database with default parameter

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I've created the following table

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (database_id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,contentCHAR(150));
```

But i can't manage to insert a row with the default option, so that database_id will auto-increment

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="mydatabase", user="Username", ")

information= 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. '

cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (database_id, content) VALUES (default, 'information');")

cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (database_id, content) VALUES (%s, %s)", (default , "information"))

conn.commit()
```

The first option take the 'default' parameter but not the content and the other do the opposite

Comment: "default" isn't text, it's a SQL thing. You tell the database you want to store a piece of text with the value "default". This doesn't fit in a integer.

Answer (score 1):

Just avoid putting any parameter on database_id so it will be generated automatically:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="mydatabase", user="Username")

information= 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. '

cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (content) VALUES (%s)", (information))

conn.commit()
```

Comment: I just tried it and it returned an error

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (content) VALUES (%s)",          (information))
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `default`. As per `postgresql`:

> PostgreSQL has the data types smallserial, serial and bigserial; these are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns. These are similar to AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases.

So just try this.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (content) VALUES (%s)", (information))
```